# NullPointerException in (MVP) Moxy's getViewState()

Tags: android, mvp, android-moxy

I installed Moxy to my project, and set annotations according to docs. But, when i launch the app, it crashes with:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.project, PID: 709
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at com.example.project.presentation.presenter.splash.SplashPresenter.checkLoggedInAndNavigate(SplashPresenter.java:35)
```

Dependencies in build.gradle:

```
    ...
    // Moxy
    compile 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.3.3'
    provided 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.3.3'
    compile 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-app-compat:1.3.3'
}
```

Here is View interface:

```
    public interface SplashView extends MvpView {

    void navigateToMainScreen();

    void navigateToLoginScreen();
}
```

Here is activity, what implements that view:

```
     public class SplashActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity implements SplashView {

        public static final String TAG = "SplashActivity";

        @InjectPresenter
        SplashPresenter mSplashPresenter;
        ...
}
```

This is the code, where it crashes:

```
@InjectViewState
public class SplashPresenter extends MvpPresenter<SplashView> {

    SplashModel mModel = new SplashModel();

    ...

    public void checkLoggedInAndNavigate() {

        if (checkLoggedIn()) {
            getViewState().navigateToMainScreen();
        } else {
            getViewState().navigateToLoginScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

When it tries to get ViewState (Which autogenerated by annotation), it throws an exception

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Hi, you can try to replace `provided 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.3.3'` to `annotationProcessor 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.3.3'`. Also, I recommend use the last version of Moxy ( now it's 1.4.5) and disable jack.

Comment: Hello! That I open same issue on GitHub :). Thanks for the help! Add an answer, please, so that I can select it as the best.

Comment: Extract it as answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to replace `provided 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.3.3'` to `annotationProcessor 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.3.3'`. Also, I recommend use the last version of Moxy (now it's 1.4.5) and disable `jack`.